# How to sort divs based on a value of a class inside of that div

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html is this:

```
<div class="comment_div">
      <span class="upvotes">4</span>
</div>

<div class="comment_div">
      <span class="upvotes">7</span>
</div>

<div class="comment_div">
      <span class="upvotes">2</span>
</div>
```

The value of `.upvotes` is dynamic so I want js/jquery to sort the divs based on the value at that time. How would I do this?

Comment: Look into tinysort http://tinysort.sjeiti.com

Comment: If they are all the same, as you show them in your question, then just sort the data before populating the div's.

Comment: Just a reminder that Stack Overflow is not a free coding service. You're supposed to do research, attempt a solution, then ask for help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following code?

```
divArr = $(".comment_div")
divArr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).find("span").text() > $(b).find("span").text() ? 1: -1;
    })
$("body").append(divArr)
```

Assuming your html is in the following format;

```
<body>
      <div class="comment_div">
            <span class="upvotes">4</span>
      </div>

      <div class="comment_div">
            <span class="upvotes">7</span>
      </div>

      <div class="comment_div">
            <span class="upvotes">2</span>
      </div>
</body>
```

And if your html is dynamic, you can rerun the code snippet again & again to resort the divs with new values.

jsFiddle link detailing above answer ; https://jsfiddle.net/1gn7no8s/

Comment: Has no efffect.

Comment: @Zorgan Ah, you'd like to sort the html? I thought you would want to get the references to the divs only.

Comment: Yes I'd like for the whole divs to be sorted and moved accordingly.

Comment: Thanks it works but it also removes all event handlers associated with my divs. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: @Zorgan can you try again? I modified the code where I update the wrapping tag object.

Comment: Thanks the event handlers work now. Still other problems so I will come back to this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

1. Select all the divs into a JQuery object.
2. Call [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) on the JQuery object to get an array of the divs.
3. Use the [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function to sort the divs in the array.
4. Create another JQuery object by passing the array of divs to [`$()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

Code:

```
var divs = $('.comment_div').get();
divs.sort(function(div1, div2) {
    function getValue(div) { return parseInt($(div).children('span:first').text(), 10); }
    var val1 = getValue(div1), val2 = getValue(div2);
    return (val1 > val2) ? 1 : ((val1 < val2) ? -1 : 0);
});
var $sortedDivs = $(divs);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n6w0pmze/)

Notes:

1. JQuery has a `.sort()` function, but it is not documented, so it is probably best not to use it.
2. I assume the values are numbers and should be sorted as such, so you need to convert them to numbers or else you will be sorting them as strings.

Comment: Thanks this works aswell. There are some other things not working so I will come back and ask.